# How does MOBAC handle groups in customWmsMapSource?

Tags: wms, mobile-atlas-creator

I'm hoping to get a custom WMS map source added to Mobile Atlas Creator (v1.9.16). This program is normally available at: http://mobac.sourceforge.net/

I plan to use Maine's Statewide Ortho WMS Services URL:
http://mapserver.maine.gov/wms/mapserv.exe?map=c:/wms/orthos.map&

From there, many groups are available, and within each are sundry sub-groups. How does MOBAC handle culling out single sources from groups and sub-groups?

Here's a sketch of what I've started:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customWmsMapSource>
    <name>MeGIS WMS Low_Tide_2008</name>
    <minZoom>0</minZoom>
    <maxZoom>18</maxZoom>
    <tileType>PNG</tileType>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <layers>lowtide2008</layers>
    <url>http://mapserver.maine.gov/wms/mapserv.exe?map=c:/wms/orthos.map&amp;</url>
    <coordinatesystem>EPSG:4326</coordinatesystem>
    <aditionalparameters>&amp;EXCEPTIONS=BLANK&amp;Styles=</aditionalparameters>
    <backgroundColor>#000000</backgroundColor>
</customWmsMapSource>
```

Here's the impotent outcome:
[image: MOBAC WMS test 01]

Comment: Welcome! Could you please include a link to the software you refer in your posting?